# How can I say how many years without being specific in my CV

Tags: resume

In my Cover letter I have something like this

"With 5 years experience in IT, I am confident in my abilities "

I do not want to be specific about how many years I have experience.

I want to say something like . I have enough experience in this field.

Comment: why do you not want to give the number? Is it because it isn't a round number? or is it because it is a large? or a small number?

Comment: If I say 5 years , which is a long time to be in the IT field. The reader would think very highly of me. The ready would think I am very intelligent or something if you know what i mean.

Comment: @Mustafa I think you are overthinking this. If you say "5 years" they will think you have "5 years experience" no more, no less.

Comment: @Mustafa This reader does not think that 5 years is a long time in IT. Neither does he think you are "very intelligent" purely because you have spent 5 years in IT.

Answer (score 10):

My first response upon reading the question was *"Why doesn't the OP want to just say how many years?"*, which then lead naturally to me assuming it's that they don't have very many and are worried I'll assume it's too low a number. So if you're trying to void drawing attention to that aspect it backfired spectacularly. It's like sticking a band-aid on a cold sore.

Now to be honest unless it's a *really* low number then I'm not generally bothered by how many years of experience someone has, since it's generally a pretty poor metric of actual *useful* experience.

If you think your level of experience is a selling point I'd simply describe myself as an "Experienced *x*" (where x is the role/skill) and then use the descriptions of roles you've done do the talking.

Answer (score 3):

They will know how many years you have when they read your CV unless your CV is also evasive, and an evasive CV is likely to be seen as a red flag by the recruiter, so you are going to have to include this information in your application even if not in the cover letter.

The point of a cover letter is to explain quickly and clearly *how* you meet the stated requirements of the specific job you are applying for or explain why they should hire you even though you don't meet the stated requirements, as well as *why* you want this particular job. Being evasive doesn't help you, you should either state it clearly if it is close e.g. "I have been working in IT for 4 and a half years" on the (reasonable) assumption that they don't actually care much about six months either way or provide an explanation of why you think you can do the job even though you don't have the stated number of years e.g. "although I have only been working professionally as a C programmer for two years, I have been programming as a hobby for over fifteen years and have contributed to many open sources projects" or whatever.

However you approach it, remember that this is a sales document. You are selling yourself as the best choice for this role. Do you find yourself more or less likely to buy from a vendor who seems evasive? The same will apply to your potential employer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your locale, you may not want to do this.  In general, companies do background checks on candidates' resumes to make sure they're telling the truth.  One of these is asking the companies "did [candidate] work here from [date 1]-[date 2], and what was their role?".  If you do not provide dates on your resume, the company won't be able to verify your employment history and you may not receive offers (or even interviews, because they will see your resume before and realize they can't background check you properly).

Unless you have an EXTREMELY good reason for doing this, don't do it.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that it would be a _very_ bad idea to indicate an actual number of years (which is false) since that can lead not only to dismissal but prosecution for fraud in many jurisdictions.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well yes, by "don't exclude your number of years", it's also implied "don't provide a false number of years".